# optaplanner performance report

Tags: performance, optaplanner

Is there a performance analysis report available for OptaPlanner which can tell for a normal server of 8 GB RAM, 4 threads CPU (or similar configuration) what is the extent to which OptaPlanner can scale in solving constraint optimization problem of Job scheduling between resources? By scale, I mean x jobs it can schedule between y resources within z amount of time (seconds taken by Optplanner to solve the optimization problem)?

Is there any other approach to get this information please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, configure the [OptaPlanner Benchmarker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpcPEieU3Cg) for your implementation and look at the generated html report.